# Kafka's retention.ms is not being enforced with Kafka 0.10.2?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

```
#!/bin/zsh
zk_servers=('10.138.0.8' '10.138.0.9' '10.138.0.16')
kafka_servers=('10.138.0.13:9092' '10.138.0.14:9092')
topics=('t1' 't2' 't1_failed' 't2_failed')


NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2; tput bold)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)

function red() {
    echo -e "$RED$*$NORMAL"
}

function green() {
    echo -e "$GREEN$*$NORMAL"
}

function yellow() {
    echo -e "$YELLOW$*$NORMAL"
}



for topic in $topics; do
   yellow "Cleaning up messages in topic @ " $topic
   yellow "=============================================================="
   $KAFKA/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $zk_servers --alter --topic $topic --config retention.ms=100
   $KAFKA/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $zk_servers --describe --topic $topic
done

red "Waiting 120 seconds for messages to expire"
sleep 120

for topic in $topics; do 
   green "Restoring config of topic @ " $topic                                                                  
   green "=============================================================="
   $KAFKA/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $zk_servers --alter --topic $topic --delete-config retention.ms                
   $KAFKA/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $zk_servers --describe --topic $topic
   $KAFKA/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list $kafka_servers --topic $topic
done
```

When I run this script - I can see that config.retention.ms has changed to 100ms, but after 120 seconds delay - I still see the same messages in all kafka topics.

**So how do I purge the messages?**

thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to wait for `log.retention.check.interval.ms` which defaults to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 11):

There is a bit more to it than the accepted answer. Kafka stores messages in log files on the file system. Those files have a rollover (configured by time or size). Once a file is no longer the current file, Kafka will no longer append to that file.

Now for the fun part: Kafka will not expire individual messages. It will (for non-compacted topics) delete whole log files once the highest timestamp of a message in that file is older than `retention.ms`. The retention time tells you that messages will be available *at least* this long, but it can potentially be available much much longer (depending on roll over configuration and message volume).

In older Kafka version, this is not based on the message timestamp but write access to the log file. Thanks to @dawsaw for pointing this out.

Comment: The behavior described here applies to versions prior to 0.10.2. Last modified time no longer is used. Instead the time index is used.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link or a KIP for that? The current docs still say "Data is deleted one log segment at a time. The log manager allows pluggable delete policies to choose which files are eligible for deletion. The current policy deletes any log with a modification time of more than N days ago, though a policy which retained the last N GB could also be useful." (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_deletes)

Comment: It's a notable change in 0.10.1 https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_10_1_breaking

Comment: I did not realize that. I'll adapt my answer, but the general point is still relevant in my opinion.